# Teleop_twist_joy problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just made the git clone from their repository https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_joy and modified to test it with the turtle sim and ROS throw me back the following message:

`cant locate node [teleop_node] in package [teleop_twist_joy]`

My code is at:
https://github.com/renanmb/teleop_test

The only changes were the topic name and the launch file that I added the turtle sim node.

Since this was a git clone I was not expecting ROS to throw especially this error message.

on GIthub catkin_make.txt is what catkin_make shows on terminal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264629/teleop_twist_joy-problem/) by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-24**:\

> Since this was a git clone I was not expecting ROS to throw especially this error message.

And this is slightly pedantic, but when asking questions I feel it's important to be accurate: 'ROS' isn't throwing any error, it's either `roslaunch` or `rosrun` which give you this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please add the full output of `catkin_make` (or `catkin build`) after building your workspace from scratch to your question. Use the *edit* button for that.

Similar to your other question, make sure that the node actually gets built and that you `source` the `devel/setup.bash` when needed.

You typically get these errors if:

1. there really is no binary with the name `teleop_twist_joy` under `devel|install/lib/$pkg_name`
2. the (search) path is not setup correctly
3. the package cache is stale / not up-to-date

Compilers/linkers failing (or mistakes in build scripts) can cause 1, nr 2 is often forgetting to `source devel/setup.bash`. Nr 3 is unfortunately not something that can really be helped (there is no easy way to detect it automatically), but can be remedied by executing `rospack profile` (*after* having made sure that you have `source`d the correct `setup.bash`).

---

Edit:

> It Worked. Thanks
> So every time I basically run into these errors I can solve by finding Compilers/linkers failing (or mistakes in build scripts), or because forgetting of `source devel/setup.bash` , or out-of-date `rospkg` cache ???

Making sure that your code compiles is a standard thing to make sure, I would say. Nothing ROS specific. If the compiler or linker don't run successfully, you don't get a binary.

If you're sure that is not the case, and your `CMakeLists.txt` is correct (which is also important, as you found out in #q264506), then a stale pkg cache is indeed often the cause.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-06-24**:
I added what catkin_make shows me in the terminal at the github

This is the explanation that was lacking on the Wiki, how to find and fix the problems.
There is a binary under `devel|install/lib/$pkg_name` called teleop_node. So if I did `source devel/setup.bash` how do I setup correctly the path?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-24**:
Can you please be a little more specific? I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to say.

What was 'lacking on the wiki'? catkin == basically CMake, and I guess some familiarity with that is assumed.

If the binary is there, and you have `source`d, try `rospack profile`.

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-06-24**:
rospack profile had show me the directories without manifest.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-24**:
`rospack profile` updates the package cache. Yes, it outputs some other lines, but you can ignore those.

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-06-24**:
It Worked. Thanks
So every time I basically run into these errors I can solve by finding Compilers/linkers failing (or mistakes in build scripts), or because forgetting of `source devel/setup.bash` , or out-of-date `rospkg` cache ???